# What is wrong with the history tag?

Tags: discussion, bug, tags

I asked [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11807/why-did-shalya-fight-on-the-side-of-the-kauravas) question on *Mahabharata* and used a *history* tag. Someone added a *mythology* tag. I removed it and it was added back again.

Before I ask a question, I would like to give some background.

A *myth* is [defined](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/myth) by *Merriam-Webster* dictionary as

> an idea or story that is believed by many people but that is not true

The *Merriam-Webster* dictionary [defines](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mythology) *mythology* as such

> the myths of a particular group or culture
>
> ideas that are believed by many people but that are not true

**The question is why am I being forced to add a *mythology* tag? What is wrong with only the *history* tag?**

PS: The *Hindus* do not like to acknowledge their own history and keep casting a strong doubt on it be using words like *mythology*. The *Chinese* and the *Japanese* promote and protect their history and culture. I wonder if this is fear, confusion about our own origins, shame, leftover intellectual colonization by the *British*, brainwashing by the *Judeo-Christian* thoughts or all of these.

Comment: From http://www.ancient.eu/mythology/: Mythology (from the Greek 'mythos' for story-of-the-people, and 'logos' for word or speech, the spoken story of a people) is the study and interpretation of often sacred tales or fables of a culture known as 'myths' or the collection of such stories which usually deal with the human condition, good and evil, human origins, life and death, the afterlife, and the gods. Myths express the beliefs and values about these subjects held by a certain culture.

Comment: My question is totally different, why is only history tag not sufficient?

Comment: @sv.: Thats a technical view of mythology used by the academics. The definitions I mentioned are what understood by normal people casting a doubt on the historicity of events.

Comment: @KeshavShrinivasan The question you marked duplicate is not duplicate in any way ? can u explain y u did that?

Comment: The question is why am I being forced to add a mythology tag?   Because our one of the moderators, [Keshav Srinivasan](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan) is going to get a first gold badge in *Mythology* tag, by this he will be the first user to get a gold badge in this site. And the sad point is many of the users are still following (and some of his socks). He will not listen to you. Its better just downvote any question tagged as *Mythology* and leave comment.

Comment: @AmitSaxena, lot of people are in favor of [removing the tag](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/new-community-consensus-on-use-of-mythology-tag), you can also upvote & comment there, and also on my [follow up](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/mods-when-are-we-going-to-remove-mythology-tag)