# Mods - When are we going to remove mythology tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, moderation

[New Community Consensus on use of Mythology Tag](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/new-community-consensus-on-use-of-mythology-tag)

very few people care about the pedantic semantic difference between myth & mythology.

for all intents & purposes, mythology means imaginary fiction.

our itihasas (iti-hasa - like so, it was) are history, although quite old to the point that people don't believe them, just as people don't believe in jesus or pretty much anything before the invention of photography, or anything after the invention of photoshop.

the tags scripture, itihasa, purana, upanishads are enough to cover our ancient kathas. I also see a user, who is a known skeptic, frequently adding the mythology tag, even going so far as to remove the scripture tag and replace it with mythology.

Are are you going to remove it ? When ?

Comment: I think this will get downvotes than upvotes and wait for some comments to be against it although I support this!

Comment: @AkshayS, the most popular answer in that thread I linked says the exact same thing - 'get rid of the tag'.

Comment: No denial!!!! Waiting for proper response!!!!! Good question!!!

Comment: @ram note that you can't "page" users who haven't commented on this post though. However, mods are automatically notified for every new meta question, so no need to page individually either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Community Consensus on use of Mythology Tag](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/new-community-consensus-on-use-of-mythology-tag)

Comment: We have not decided to remove or rename the mythology tag yet, that doesn't mean you should start removing mythology tag from questions.

Comment: @Pandya, in that case, there must also be a moratorium on adding the tag to questions.

Comment: @ram Usage of tag are defined by [tag excerpt](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/mythology/info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TODAY !

The answer for *'When are we going to remove the mythology tag?'* - is TODAY AUG 1 2020.

It's DONE.
All *mythology* tags have been removed from existing questions, and the tag has been blacklisted, so no future questions can be tagged as *mythology*.

The primary reason to remove it is - *mythology* means false/fake/fiction, for all people except a few. Look up its [dictionary meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/myths)

As I mentioned earlier - **scripture** is the most suitable English-word tag to replace it.
Because all our epics are actual life accounts of Avatars with morals on how to lead life.

If a person already knows which scripture (**'praman'**), they can use **'itihasa**', or **'purana'**, **'ramayana'** or **'mahabharata'** or **'vedas'** or **'upanishads'**, or at the very least **'katha'**.

If it is not part of any known scripture, but part of recent recorded history, hey can use **'parampara'** (tradition or history).

If it is neither scripture nor recent history, and primarily hearsay, we can tag it as **'folklore'**

Thanks to everyone who worked towards blacklisting that misleading tag... and to the naysayers too.

जयम् !

Answer (score -2):

The discussion on the tag has already been done in the post you linked. In the post, the answer which is the most acceptable asks to remove the tag. It's futile to discuss the same here.

Also, this site is HinduismSE, the tags should square well with the belief system of 'Hinduism'. Mythology tag is more suited for SkeptismSE or StorySE (if the site lurks); there is no word in scriptures for any event which can be translated to mythology. 'Hindu' scriptures claim 'supposed' mythology as history & since this site is based on Hinduism or gives value to scriptural claims only we should stick with scriptural 'itihaas' than with skeptical 'mythology'. 'Mythology' tag is unnecessary encroachment here on HinduismSE. Whether any 'X' event actually happened or not is not our concern, it's concern of historians or whateverian. But if such happening is documented in scriptures as Itihaasas then call it itihaas as again - this is HinduismSE. Of course, even the word 'Hinduism' is also not scriptural & need to be get rid of in distant future but as of now we don't have any replacement of the word 'Hinduism' unlike 'Mythology'where we have very apt replacement called 'itihaas'.

At last, this post is not to justify for existence of the tag in either of the direction but on implementation of the decision carried out in the post posted by @Tejaswi. So, mods should decide looking at community consensus in [New Community Consensus on use of Mythology Tag](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/new-community-consensus-on-use-of-mythology-tag) about fate of the inflammatory tag.

I am not arguing in either support or oppose of the tag but asking when the effect of the post posed by Tejaswi going to come into picture? Or the post and answers there were mere linguistic drama?

Comment: Upvotes alone do not decide the consensus on meta sites. [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177550/357396). The most upvoted answer on that thread gives a wrong usage guidance on purana and itihasa tags. Not every story is a purana or itihasa. We are using mythology for any story and not for "scripture". Hinduism is outside scriptures too. We are Hinduism.SE and not scripture.SE

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I really don't care how any decision is carried out here all I am saying is when the effect of the Tejaswi post going to come into picture in whatever manner possible? And you would decide alone what is wrong or right if not votes? Btw, I tried hard to get impressed but ScriptureSE is very lame and generalized name to be used in replacement of HinduismSE provided the usage of word Hinduism too need to be pondered; VaishnavismSE, however specific, would have made more sense...

Comment: Having said that, as of now we don't have any replacement of Hinduism so we are forced to use the word 'Hinduism' but we have scriptural replacement for 'mythology' & that is itihaas.

Comment: Thanks @Zanna to point out absurdity.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, we can use epics instead of mythology if we really need a tag other than itihasa, purana, vedas & scriptures. can you some mythologies that is not part of itihasa & purana ? whatever be the case, the word 'mythology' has a very popular meaning as something that's imagination/false.

Comment: @ram There are many stories which are not part of Ramayana, Mahabharata and Puranas. Iitihasa in common terms mean "Ramayana and Itihasa". You take taking the meaning of itihasa as history but you are not ready to take original meaning of mythos as stories.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, I don't take the meaning of itihasa as history. i take the meaning of itihasa as ramayana & mahabharata only. can you give examples of mythologies not from itihasa & purana ? 'mythos / stories' all these words have a negative connotation for majority of people. do you understand that ? 10 people saying 'mythology' does not mean fiction, will not convince 90 people who are saying 'mythology' means fiction.

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. Have you read Tejaswi's meta post and its argument to remove or continue the usage of tag? There are many mistakes in the argument and who knows tagging practice on SE can refute it. But the answer will receive downvotes again. I am sure it received upvotes just because it asks to remove the tag. The arguments posted are not in line with help center. What makes sense and useful is taken even if it gets less votes. Any answer if it is saying useless and got more votes will be discarded. This is not just Vaishnavism.SE. It is Hinduism.SE where everyone and everything is included.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma  Who would decide where is mistake or what makes sense? you? What 'you' dislike or oppose is not necessarily wrong. Live with that. You are basically saying - the answer can not be accepted just because it's not acceptable to you.

Comment: I already said "inline with help center". Read the comment carefully. I strongly believe all people can read and understand how tagging is done and have brains here to decide what can be useful and what is not in the long run.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes, 'All people have brains here to decide what can be useful and what is not in the long run.' & they decided to remove the tag completely in the earlier post.

Comment: Please read all the comments I posted carefully. In the very first comment I posted under this answer, I linked how is consensus is made on SE sites and meta sites. Upvotes do not always reflect the consensus. We should see what answer is saying. [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177550/357396).

Comment: @Sarvabhouma You also read [this](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/21/Appeal-to-Authority).

Answer (score -3):

Any word which has any possible connotation of 'false/imagination/fiction/lie' must not be used when referring to our scriptures.

Itihasa, Purana & Scripture are enough to categorize most mythology questions. For remaining, we can deal on case by case basis. Within those two, we have 2 itihasa + 18 purana = 20 different tag options for detail.

Here are definitions of alternate words proposed earlier, and why they are all bad :

**Myth**:

> 1. a traditional story, especially one concerning the early history of a
>      people or explaining some natural or social phenomenon, and typically
>      involving supernatural beings or events.
> 2. a widely held but **false** belief or idea.

**Mythology**:

> collection/study of myths

So, @KeshavSrinivasan's comment :

> And by the way, while the word myth has these two disparate meanings
>   in English, the word mythology has only one meaning and that is
>   related to the non-pejorative usage of the word myth, i.e. "a
>   traditional story, especially one concerning the early history of a
>   people or explaining some natural or social phenomenon, and typically
>   involving supernatural beings or events."

doesn't seem to have google's blessing - since mythology is just a collection of myths, it could mean a 1. collection of facts, or 2. collection of lies.

**Legend**:

> a traditional story sometimes popularly regarded as historical but
>   **unauthenticated**.

**Story**:

> an account of **imaginary** or real people and events told for
>   entertainment.

**Epic**:

> a long poem, typically one derived from ancient oral tradition,
>   narrating the deeds and adventures of heroic or **legendary** figures or
>   the history of a nation.

Since all this confusion arises with English translations, we still need a word to denote stories but which doesn't have the common negative connotation as imaginative fiction, so my suggestion is to use the original Sanskrit word

> **Katha**

Why do we even need tags anyway.. They're just an additional piece of information. Keep in mind, this stackoverflow site was created for programming questions with so many different languages, so that people can get alerts for specific tags relating to their expertise. Even if we get rid of the tagging practice on HSE, it won't affect much.

Comment: Your approach was very weak. You restarted a battle which was already won in the other post in the past. This post should have been focused on implementation of the decision carried out in the previous post not to justify something.

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. eh? i'm doing both. i already commented on the original post months back asking for implementation, and no response.

Comment: Sorry, Your strategy was extremely inefficient here. There was no need of 'doing both'. You should have kept discussion limited to effect of the earlier post & its implementation only.

Comment: @Mr.Sigma, guess we just have to agree to disagree. if the battle was already won, fighting it again won't cause a loss. if it did, that means people's minds have changed, in which case the battle needs to be fought again anyways. if you agree 1+1 = 2, saying it again won't cause you to change ur mind, nor will it affect the truth. i want to reiterate my reasoning for removing the tag again here, because in the original post, my answer didn't garner much attention. any case, we're on the same page about the tag, so all good.

Comment: Wrong analogy. You might not find supporting people again for they might not be active anymore. Btw, I am closing my discussion in this thread. Take care. :)

Comment: @Mr.Sigma, so ? that means the battle stays won. it doesn't harm the original sentiment in any way. at worst, this post is redundant.