# Can users who constantly engage in edit-wars with other users over tags be banned from the site?

Tags: discussion, support, editing, moderation, user-suspension

Does the system allow for banning users who engage in disruptive behavior of the following nature;

1. User doesn't like the use of a particular tag. Instead of bringing the issue to notice on meta, user tries to fix the issue themselves i.e., take matters into their own hands. User doesn't believe in community voting, arriving at a consensus, etc.
2. User doesn't like certain type of questions they read on the site. They find the content objectionable even if the questions don't break the [Code of Conduct](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct). Instead of flagging or coming to meta to discuss the problem with these types of questions, user now asks mock questions on the main site to show the problem with the other questions they don't like. Other users who also don't like the original questions now upvote these mock questions.

What can be done with such users?

Can they be temporarily banned from the site to prevent them from doing this over & over?

With regard to mock questions, can the 'rude or abusive' flag be used since technically it's an abuse of the SE system? Are mods of this site going to honor the flag?

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035) MSE post says:

> What makes something rude or abusive and when should I flag it?
>
> A post should be marked as rude or abusive (formerly known as offensive) if it contains hate speech, obscenities, abuse against people, or **abuse of the community or system**, i.e., a clear violation of the be-nice policy.

Comment: This can be easily resolved by the mods by locking the posts ..

Comment: Why on earth is this primarily opinion based?

Comment: I know that moderators send messages to them explaining the editing etiquette and warning them not to perform superfluous edits any further. Locking the posts is not the action on user. It is only on a post. Since you are asking whether there is an action, locking is no the answer. It doesn't really affect the user.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, exactly ! we should all follow that advice and not perform superfluous edits like adding 'mythology' tag.

Comment: I suggest  separate  question for ", can the 'rude or abusive' flag be used since technically it's an abuse of the SE system?"

Comment: @Pandya - https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/mods-when-are-we-going-to-remove-mythology-tag

Answer (score 6):

There is a [provision for banning a user form suggesting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252991/260388) an edit if s/he doesn't have [edit privileges](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).

Well, usually edit/roll-back wars are handled by [locking posts](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts) which are under dispute and by guiding users engaged in edit wars not to (do that) but if a user having edit-privileges observed continuously engaged in edit/roll-back war on multiple posts even after suggested not to (do so) by moderators then Yes, moderators can [suspend](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) him/her depending on *how much harm or destruction is done by a user to the community*.

> User doesn't like the use of a particular tag...
>   User doesn't like certain type of questions...

This site doesn't entertain liking and disliking of users, that's the thing users need to understand and learn. If a user having some suggestions, s/he should post it on meta. If you find rude/offensive behavior that hurts then you can flag.

Comment: For question on flagging a post on rude/abusive, I suggest to post a separate question.

Comment: If a user constantly removes a tag due to dislike though it is applicable to the question, what action are the moderators going to to take? and when? Should other always flag to get to your (moderator) attention? Don't you see home page what is happening or the moderation room?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, if a user constantly adds a tag due to their like though it is not applicable to the question, what action are the moderators going to take? and when? Should other always flag to get your (moderator) attention? Don't you see home page what is happening or the moderation room? When are you going to remove the mythology tag which most users on this site want removed ? Until that matter is resolved, people should stop adding (or adding back) that tag to questions. If moderators don't responds to that, then users have no choice but to take matters into their own hands.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, it has been more than 1.5 YEARS since the [mythology tag](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/new-community-consensus-on-use-of-mythology-tag) question first came on meta. Did you raise concerns that why mods are not taking action on it? But now that someone is removing the tag and it starts affecting your opinions, you want mods to act on it quickly ? That's understandable, but also apply same urgent expectations to that question. I raised it on meta, and waited for long, but if police doesn't help with law, common man takes up arms.

Comment: @ram Mods are not police, we are not common man. There is no crime is being done by adding a tag. It has been said over 100 times by now what mythology tag is for.But users are only taking the wrong meaning to suit their interests. There are over 100 tags on this site. All tags should be treated equally. If a user adds Rakshasa tag, it doesn't mean they are Rakshasa or supporting them. Tagging is based on question. Don't indulge in edit wars to remove the tags you dislike. The arguments made in the linked question are poor and not according to SE. Emotions do not work here on SE.

Comment: @Pandya Is there a bug in moderators queue? Actually moderators get notified when there are a couple of rollbacks on the same post. They try to lock the post or post something under the post. Are the moderators supporting edit wars?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, exactly ! no crime is being done by removing a tag either, so why call for ban ? It has been said over 100 times by now that mythology tag is misleading. If a user adds a mythology tag, they either support the commonly accepted definition (it is fake), or they support the orthodox definition (it is true) - if they are in former category, they are wrong. if they are in latter category, they are ignorantly acting against their own beliefs, because MOST people believe mythology means fake. You're right, emotions don't work. Let's just go by voting and consensus.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, would you prefer it if Mods locked a post AFTER mythology tag was removed ?

Comment: @ram no, you should not take the action of removing mythology tag from questions in your hand when whether to remove/rename the mythology tag has not decided yet.

Comment: @Pandya, can other users take the action of adding mythology tag when decision has not been made yet ?

Comment: @ram As far as if questions satisfies the [current tag excerpt](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/mythology/info), then yes.

Comment: @Pandya, the current tag excerpt has a meaning completely different from what people understand it as. This is not some knee-jerk reaction I'm doing. The original post to remove the tag was created 1.5 YEARS AGO. No action by mods till date. You want users to keep quiet like sheep ? Even the user who made that post asking for my ban recently made a comment "you are trying to mix history and mythology" - it's clear he doesn't accept the tag-excerpt definition, yet he continues to add the tag? he is using the law to spread lies. do you think that's ok?

Answer (score 3):

The title and the body asks different questions.

**For the title:**

Yes, they can be banned.

**For the first point:**

If a user thinks the added tag is wrong, they can rollback the edit as said in the [help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

> Users with more than 1,000 reputation are considered trusted community members and can edit posts without going through the review process.

So, taking into their hands and editing the question to correct tags or content is fine up to some extent.

BUT, here's the key. If a user constantly edits which he likes without following proper tagging guidelines and editing guidelines, that revision should be kept which is followed through community consensus and help center. *Tagging is not personal choice*. We have to tag it based on question's topic. E.g If I personally have problem with [ramayana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramayana) or [mahabharata](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahabharata) due to my faith, I can't just remove the tag from questions after earning a reputation of 1000 or 5000.

**For a user with edit privileges, there's no edit ban. There is a suspension altogether.** If a user with privileges constantly indulges in a series of bad edits and superfluous edits, the user will be contacted by moderators. The revisions will be restored to previous versions. If the behaviour continues, the user *can be suspended for a period*.(See [Is there an equivalent for suggested edit ban for 2k+ users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327399/357396) from Meta Stack Exchange) So, it is moderators' call when to take actions on user with above mentioned qualities.

**Second point:**

If the questions are posted just to mock the system, they will be faced a question ban and eventually a suspension too. Questions and answers which are for trolling are not allowed on the site as far as I know. For this, we can use a moderator intervention flag. I wouldn't suggest you to use Rude flags. Rude flags can be used if a user is constantly abusing the system by writing gibberish like "asjydnkfeiy". Even though it's not actually harassment, we can use red flags because it's abusing system. This also depends on moderators when to act on flags and what action to take.

Comment: you're exactly right ! If someone personally is a fan of *mythology* tag due to their beliefs, they can't just add the tag to questions after earning a reputation of 10000 or 15000

Answer (score 0):

I am highlighting the exceptional case if the case happened due to an exceptional tag.

If only a single user doesn't like a particular tag owing to his dislike towards to tag, the user needs to understand the perspective of community & site. If he doesn't understand, like other answer has said, there are provisions to deal with the situation.

But if consensus or community or majority of users themselves show opposition towards a particular tag then @Moderators need to arrive at valid & consistent conclusion regarding the particular controversial tag, not towards a user who is engaging in such edit war. Such edit war due to a controversial tag is rooted in indecisiveness of the use of tag only, nothing otherwise.

I opine the use of the controversial tag should come to halt until @Moderators arrive at final decisive conclusion regarding the tag which majority of users or community don't like. Because if frequent tagging a controversial tag doesn't make for an edit war then how frequent untagging of the same tag can make for an edit war?

P.S: Current controversial tag is [mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology)

Comment: thanks for the support ! even the user sv recently made a comment [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34538/in-which-languagelipi-are-the-vedas-written) : "You are trying to mix history and mythology." - clearly he does not believe the 'tag-excerpt' definition of mythology (and he's right, most folks think mythology means made up stories), yet he continues to add the tag to questions - obviously he wants the world to think these things are fake. and when I remove that tag, he calls for my ban.

Comment: @ram Yeah. That comment is a very good example what people understand with the word mythology.