# Is it acceptable to post links that belittle a particular Hindu sect or Hinduism in general?

Tags: discussion

My post is related to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42894/what-is-the-basis-for-the-claim-of-vaishnavaites-that-unless-one-is-duly-initiat) question, where the writer of the question posted a link to [this website](http://www.ramana-talk-mailer.appspot.com/read?post_name=Letter&index=67). If you read the content posted on the website, it tries to belittle the beliefs of a particular Hindu sect. With due apologies to members of that sect, let me post the relevant contents here -

> When I was on the hill, some Vaishnavaites used to
> come there to see me. There are, as you know, two sections
> amongst Vaishnavaites, Vadakalai and Thenkalai. I used to
> speak to these visitors in accordance with their respective
> traditions, as I lose nothing by doing so. When, however,
> they thought that I was on their side and wanted me to have
> Samasrayanam, I declined. They believe that no one will be
> permitted into Vaikuntam (heaven) unless he is duly initiated.
> I used to ask them, **‘Show me even one person who has gone
> to Vaikuntam with his body.’** According to their traditions,
> they do not accept Sayujyam (absorption into the deity). **They
> say, ‘Sri Maha Vishnu is in heaven, Vaikuntam. Released souls
> sit around him and serve him.’ How will all find
> accommodation there? Perhaps they sit close together
> shoulder to shoulder? They alone should know.** Not only
> that. It seems there is a mantra which declares that they
> surrender their all to their Guru at the time they receive
> Samasrayanam. It is enough if the mantra is recited and a
> dakshina (offering or donation) is given to the Guru. The
> surrender is over, and it does not matter whatever is done
> afterwards; a seat is reserved for them in Vaikuntam. What
> more is needed? **That is the opinion of some of them. It is
> mere delusion to think of arpana (offering), so lightly.**

The above statements clearly belittle the beliefs of one sect of Hinduism. My question is whether it is fine to post links to such websites. If this is fine, then tomorrow somebody can post links to websites where Hindu religion itself is belittled or denigrated. Someone can post links to websites that say that worshiping idols is same as worshiping inanimate, lifeless rocks and idol worshippers are deluded? Are posting such links acceptable?

**Edit:** There are two such questions with the same link given in each of them - [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42894/what-is-the-basis-for-the-claim-of-vaishnavaites-that-unless-one-is-duly-initiat) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42869/has-any-vaishnava-who-belongs-to-vadakalai-or-thenkalai-section-and-is-duly-ini). I flagged both questions for moderator intervention.

Comment: It appears you have not commented in or posted an answer under this question [Purge and blacklist the tag Neo-vedanta](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1933/3869).  Would like to do now?

Comment: @idol worshipper. I neither meant nor intent to offend anyone. But one thing, those highlighted portions do not belittle VAs rather misrepresenting them. Especially that accomodation in vaikunta part, we believe Narayana is Brahman, also we believe in sayujyam too( Maharshi claimed  we don't) the Universe itself is situated in him, it is funny how he could not accomodate some souls. Seems Maharshi loves Advaita so much that he is misrepresenting other traditions to his devotees, not everything some lay vaishnavas tell becomes true.

Comment: @idolworshipper: Let me clarify on one issue here.  It all started with my requesting the members and the moderator to purge the tag Neo-Vedanta.  If you go back and check my questions and answers till then, you can find that they are posted without using any offensive language against any one, though I had stated on many issues, treating them as interpolations.  However, when the moderator refused to purge the tag neo-vedanta and the Vaishnavaite fanatic members continued to troll me, I had decided to retort.  That is all to say from my side

Comment: @idolworshipper: do you think removal the tag neo-vedanta is a small issue?  The Vaishnavaite fanatics have been posting questions, using that tag, to demean advaitins.  Even yesterday, the member Ikshvaku posted another question using that tag.  Is it not provocating?  Why the other members remained silent on this issue?  When majority of the members, including the Vaishnava fanatics, are silent on that issue, why are you people are raising hue and cry over a few questions?  Please remain silent on this issue. Take it in stride and move on.

Comment: @idolworshipper: I stopped commenting on the moderator, because of your request.  What is the moderator doing, when I flagged the issue of calling me 'troll' by another Vaishnava Fanatic member?  You and other members are getting offended when I called the moderator "lone biased moderator".  Have you ever thought why did I feel when a fanatic calls me "troll" in this site and everyone remains silent?

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV Who is 'I" in the quote in your question? Is it Raman Maharshi speaking those words?

Comment: It is acceptable if the one posting such links wants to clarify/verify the content of such links or asking how those people being belittled defend their beliefs. May not be acceptable if OP wants to further belittle those sects subtly or indirectly.

Comment: @idolworshipper: You can take one pretext or the other on the issue of removal of the tag neo-vedanta.  It is your problem.  I have my own views on this topic.  thanks

Comment: @idolworshipper You seem to be over sensitive to anything that you think as slightly against the Vaishnavas. Then you have to learn to deal with it. This is not a Vaisnava forum that such things will be censored.. There is nothing wrong in the quote.. BTW have you seen this "This **rascal Ramakrishna** did it"   .. Someone calling Ramakrishna Paramhamsa a rascal from this question here : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/41122/did-ramakrishna-eat-cows-meat-during-his-time-as-a-muslim. Nobody has objected, the question is still there, not many downvotes on it too.

Comment: @Rickross: The narration was a part of letter written to her brother by a widower, Suri Nagamma.  She used to stay in ashram and practice SPIRITUALITY as per Sri Maharshi's directions.  The English version is of her letter.  She might have used the word "I", referring to Sri Maharshi, while narrating the incident.  Actually, Sri Maharshi rarely used the word "I".

Comment: Okay thanks ... @SrimannarayanaKV

Comment: I have deleted my previous comment @idolworshipper

Comment: @idolworshipper: the comment was deleted later by whom that I do not know.  If you want to see the comment, please go through [this question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1976/3869).  This question has already received 9 downvotes, most probably from Vaishnava fanatics, and hence not appearing in the list.

Comment: @Rickross. //There is nothing wrong in the quote// In that quote Maharshi is clearly insulting both Sri Vaishnavas and their philosophy. Of course, nothing is wrong for a shakta advaitin..everything is wrong for a Sri Vaishnava. **I am not against quoting it** but content of that quote is insulting us and OP's intent is also further insulting us.

Comment: @Satya Here we are allowed to quote from the sayings of well known saints, Acharyas etc. So that is why there is nothing wrong. Even I have produced a quote by a Vaishnava scholar calling Ramakrishna Paramahamsa a rascal. So, the point is if someone quotes Davaitin scholar where he mentions Adi Shankara as a demon even that will be allowed.

Comment: I started calling them fanatic, only after the moderator refused to take action on that member @idolworshipper

Comment: Do you mean to say that mere deletion of a comment, is suffice?

Comment: If that is your answer, then why are you questioning me, if I call a group of members, fanatic? Take it in stride and move on

Comment: Why should I say?  Cannot a moderator think how to act, when a member uses offensive language against another?

Comment: There is nothing to reconcile. We ourselves should not try to demean but at the same time we can also quote well known saints like Ramana Maharishi. And, BTW all those debates and fights are the outcomes of terrible intolerance of one particular Hindu sect. Every old user here knows that @idolworshipper

Comment: Why are you asking on behalf of the moderator, who is not acting as expected?  Even if say something, can you implement it? No.  Again, the same has to be referred to the moderator for action.

Comment: @idolworshipper: Have you go through this question - [How do Sri Vaishnavas know that the Alwars were incarnations of Nitya Suris?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34136/3869).  So far no one provided the answer.  How can anyone answer such strange question?  Why was it not closed yet?

Comment: No.  It cannot be answered from scriptures.  That was why it has remained unanswered yet.  I can understand that you know this, but are preferring to side with the writer

Comment: @Srimannarayana K V. That cannot be answered and should be closed but that question did not hurt beliefs of anyone.

Comment: That question did not hurt beliefs of anyone!  Is it because it was posted by a Sri Vaishnavaite?

Comment: It indeed questioning Sri Vaishnava beliefs other sects need not worry about that question. @Srimannarayana

Comment: If you take that stand, then please don't worry about my questions also.

Comment: My latest question is also asking from scriptures only.  what problem do you perceive?

Comment: I said my latest question.  It did not belittle any one.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/42894

Comment: As per site rules, we can refer anything, as question content.  It is because you are taking a biased view, my question is appearing to you so.  Take an unbiased view

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV, when you said 'Sri Rama is not an avatar of Vishnu', did Sri Rama make an account on this site and make a big-deal about Anti-Vaishnava Fanatics like yourself deriding him ? Like I said before, you threw the first stone. You were the first to offend. Why complain when the stone falls back on your head ? I suggest you "Please remain silent on this issue. Take it in stride and move on", like you advised to another user.

Comment: @ram:   I get nauseated feeling with your fanatic/irresponsible comments.  Please do not try to interact with me, either in Meta or in Main site.  Thanks

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV, *"Have you ever thought why did I feel when a fanatic calls me 'troll' in this site and everyone remains silent?"* - Did that 'fanatic' user call you a troll all this time in all the previous interactions ? Have you ever thought what most users of this site feel when you say 'Sri Rama is not an avatar of Vishnu' ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to always follow the "code of conduct" of stack exchange on HSE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/is-it-possible-to-always-follow-the-code-of-conduct-of-stack-exchange-on-hse)

Comment: I've already answered a similar query of yours [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1866/2995): "The CoC only comes into play when a user takes the offensive stuff X had said about Y in their commentary and starts using it against current day followers of Y in comments and chat."